# Using the flutter_quill plugin, how to add the request header displayed by the network image

Tags: flutter, dart, rich-text-editor, flutter-plugin

Using the flutter_quill plugin, how to add the request header displayed by the network image?
For example, in the flutter widget, you can configure the header to display network pictures, so how to add it when flutter_quill displays network images?

```
Image.network(
        url,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        headers: const {"User-Agent": "xxxx"}, // add this
      ),
```

I added a network picture, but it must have a specific header to display normally, otherwise a default picture will be displayed

Answer (score -2):

The `flutter_quill` package does not directly handle network images. Instead, it relies on the `flutter_quill_image_upload` package for handling image uploads. Therefore, the request headers for network images are not configurable within the `flutter_quill` package itself.

To add request headers when loading network images using `flutter_quill`, you would need to modify the implementation of the `flutter_quill_image_upload` package or create a custom solution. Here's a general outline of the steps you can follow:

1. Fork the `flutter_quill_image_upload` package repository or create a new package to handle image uploads.
2. Modify the image upload logic to include request headers for network images. You would need to add support for passing and handling request headers during the image upload process.
3. Use the modified or custom package in your Flutter project, replacing the default `flutter_quill_image_upload` dependency.
4. Configure the desired request headers when using the `flutter_quill` editor widget to display network images. This may involve providing the headers as part of the image source URL or passing them as options to the modified or custom image upload logic.

Keep in mind that this approach requires advanced knowledge of Flutter and package development. It's important to carefully review the documentation and implementation details of the `flutter_quill_image_upload` package and consider the implications of modifying or creating a custom solution for your specific needs.

Comment: I did not search for `flutter_quill_image_upload` package, even on GitHub there is no result

Comment: you can check any other package for image uploading on pub.dev and use it with flutter_quill. You've to upload and save images explicitly.

Comment: This sounds too complicated, I guess it's hard for me to do it. :(

Comment: Ok. I'll share more simple solution or might be any code snippet i found one of my friend who has already done this. I'll update my answer. Keep checking!

Comment: @zhangsan Could you please explain your question in more details? kindly add SS for both what you're getting and what you're required. I've seen the flutter_quill it converts the image to base64 encoding you can save the same encoding and show that image anywhere and send that encoding as string over the network.

Comment: For the picture I want to display, the server where it is located will add a header verification to the picture, and the correct picture will be displayed only when there is a correct header, otherwise a default picture will be provided. This should be easy to understand.

Comment: @zhangsan for that you need a custom script. while uploading data to server you can append your customer header value with base64 encoding of image. server will verify and also you can verify if such header is appended to that encoding while showing image in your app. I hope you get my point.

Comment: Your 8 most recent answers all appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.